# OCUnit wants me to install Rosetta

Tags: objective-c, unit-testing, xcode, ocunit

I followed the instructions on Unit Testing objective C from Apple: http://developer.apple.com/tools/unittest.html

I installed the latest version of OCUnit, but when I compile, software update starts and tells me I need to install Resetta. What's going on?

Answer (score 1):

Those instructions are outdated.  You shouldn't need to install OCUnit at all, it's built into XCode 2.1 and later.  Perhaps you downloaded an old PowerPC version?

the [iOS Development Guide](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Xcode/Conceptual/iphone_development/000-Introduction/introduction.html) has a [section on Unit Testing](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Xcode/Conceptual/iphone_development/135-Unit_Testing_Applications/unit_testing_applications.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007959-CH20-SW3) that's much more up-to-date.

There's also one for [Mac OS X](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/UnitTesting/0-Introduction/introduction.html).

Comment: Followed those instructions and the same thing happened. Do I need to do something to get rid of the PPC library I installed?